# How to fix the increase and decrease value of my shopping card?

Tags: javascript, php

[enter image description here][1]When I add a product in my shopping card and I decrease or increase the value, everything works. But when I want to add another product in my shopping card and I want to decrease or increase the value of that product, it change the value of the first one. I don't know where the problem is.

```
$shoppingCardItem = ShoppingCardDAO::getShoppingCardItems();

foreach ($shoppingCardItem as $item) {

<tr>
    <td><a href="detail.php?productId=<?php echo $item->getProductId(); ?>"><img class="card-img-top" src="./img/<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getImage(); ?>"></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $item->getProduct()->getName(); ?></td>
    <td class="card-text">&euro; <?php echo $item->getTotalExclVAT(); ?><small> (Excl. VAT)</small></td>
    <td class="card-text">&euro; <?php echo $item->getTotalInclVAT(); ?><small> (Incl. VAT)</small></td>

    <td>
       <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="postcheck" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $item->getProductId() ?>">
        <input type="button" class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" name="decrease" value="-">
        <input type="text" id="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $item->getQuantity(); ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" name="increase" value="+">
        <td><input type="submit" name="deleteShoppingCardItem" value="Delete" class="col-0.5 btn btn-danger"></td>                               
       </form>
    </td>
</tr>


// link image
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE1k2.png
```

Comment: It's probably because your `forEach` outputs several items with the same `id` attribute. There should only be one element with a given `id` in an HTML document. Try using a class instead.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, Do I have to change all the id attribute by class?

Comment: Yes, I would. And obviously change any Javascript code that interacts with these elements so that it works with classes rather than IDs. (You haven't actually included any JS code in your question, even though you used the `javascript` tag.)